# Circular dependency in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

For school we have to write our own WebApi using the .NET Entity Core Framework. I've written my api but when I tried to use it in swagger, it always returned a HTTP 500 error: internal server error. I downloaded Fiddler to start debugging and came across a circular dependency error in my repository but I can't figure out where this would take place.

The interface (for mock testing)

```
public interface IVisitorRepository
{
    Visitor GetBy(string email);
    void AddVisitor(Visitor visitor);
    void SaveChanges();
}
```

The concrete class

```
public class VisitorRepository : IVisitorRepository 
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<Visitor> _visitors;

    public VisitorRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, IVisitorRepository visitorRepository) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _visitors = _context.Visitors;
    }

    public void AddVisitor(Visitor visitor) 
    {
        _visitors.Add(visitor);
    }

    public Visitor GetBy(string email) 
    {
        return _visitors.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Email == email);
    }

    public void SaveChanges() 
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I've scoped it in my pipeline.

It's a JWT token based login and register api (that's what we need to make) and here's my register method (the method I'm testing)

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<String>> Register(RegisterDTO model) 
    {
        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor(model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName, model.Email, model.PhoneNumber, model.Country);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded) 
        {
            _visitorRepository.AddVisitor(visitor);
            _visitorRepository.SaveChanges();
            string token = GetToken(user);
            return Created("", token);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

The exception:

> InvalidOperationException: A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'DigitizedApi.Models.Repositories.IVisitorRepository'. DigitizedApi.Models.Repositories.IVisitorRepository(DigitizedApi.Data.Repositories.VisitorRepository) -> DigitizedApi.Models.Repositories.IVisitorRepository

Comment: Your `VisitorRepository` (which implements `IVisitorRepository`) has a dependency on `IVisitorRepository` (itself). Check the constructor.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma wow that was dumb, Thanks a lot, that fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is your `VisitorRepository` (which implements `IVisitorRepository`) has a dependency on `IVisitorRepository` itself.

Actually it should be as follows:

```
public class VisitorRepository : IVisitorRepository 
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<Visitor> _visitors;

    public VisitorRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
        _visitors = _context.Visitors;
    }
    .........
}
```